Laravel schedule logs are not at same place as Laravel task logs
I have Laravel 8 app in development mode that has task scheduled on every 20 seconds:
`protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
{
        $event = $schedule->exec('php artisan app:drive-dispatch');
        $event->output = '/dev/stdout';
        $event->everyTwentySeconds();
}`



This $event->output  = '/dev/stdout'; should redirect output to standard output.
And there is cron that runs php artisan schedule:run on every minute. My Laravel log is set up to log on stdout:
'stdout' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => env('LOG_STDOUT_FORMATTER'),
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stdout',
            ],
        ],

When I manually run php artisan schedule:run in var/www/html folder I can see scheduler logs on console:
'/usr/local/bin/php' 'artisan' app:drive-dispatch >> '/dev/stdout' 2>&1  
Running ['artisan' app:drive-dispatch] .... 1,219ms DONE


but there aren't any command log.
On the other hand, when manually start my command php artisan command_name I can see my command logs on console:
[2024-06-28 21:02:26] local.DEBUG: Combinations: [null]
[2024-06-28 21:02:26] local.DEBUG: Best match: {"weight":0,"driverRides":[]}
I want to log command logs on console where scheduler task is started.
It seems that is scheduler and task are separated processes and cannot share same console. Has anyone had similar problem and is it possible to solve.
Thanks in advance.
